# How to: log and anlyze clicks, pageviews and sessions to optimize conversion

Tags: mysql, mongodb, logging, analytics

We have a medium size e-commerce site. We sell books. On said site we have promotions, user recommendations, regular book pages, related books, etcetera. Quite similar to amazon.com except ofcourse the volume of the site.

We have a traditional LAMP setup, where the M still stands for MariaDB.

TPTB want to log and analyze user behaviour in order to optimize conversion.

Bottom line, each click has to be logged, I think. (I fear)

This will add up to a few million clicks every month. The system has to be able to go back in time at least 3 years.

Questions that might be asked the system are: Given a page (eg: homepage), and clicks on a promotional banner, which color of said banner gives the best conversion. Now split that question into new and returning customers. (Multi-dimensional or A/B-testing) Or, given a view of book A and B, which books do users buy next. The range of queries is going to be very wide. Aggregating the data will be pointless.

I have serious doubts about MySQL's ability to provide a good platform for storing, analyzing and querying this data. We could store the rows, feeding them to MySQL via RabbitMQ as to avoid delays, but query and analyze this data efficiently might not be optimal in MySQL, given 50M rows.

There have been a number of articles about using MongoDB to store analytical data. But all the posts seem to increment a counter in a document (pre-aggregating the data), which is not good enough for us.

The big question is: Is there any database (or other system) that is particularly well-suited to store and analyze data like this? Might MySQL still do the trick? Am I correct in my assessment that MongoDB probably might not be of any added value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you only want to have reports with aggregated data done say once a day (As opposed to "live")? If that's the case, I would suggest to use Hadoop, as it allows you to run massive Map/Reduce jobs running this aggregations for you, and then present you with a report. At this amount of data, any "live" solution will just not work.

If you don't want to mess with the complexity of Hadoop and Map/Reduce, then perhaps MongoDB might work. It has quite a powerful aggregation framework that can be tasked to do many aggregations in a sort-of-live environment. It's not really meant for running at every pageview, but it's also not a "let's do this once a day" kinda thing. It depends a little bit on your data aggregation requirements whether the Aggregation Framework can help you, but if it doesn't, then MongoDB also supports Map/Reduce for some more complex tasks (at a slower pace). MongoDB is a quite a good fit, as you can have large write performance - if one node doesn't work, you can always shard to have higher write performance.

Comment: I'm certainly not expecting to real-time analyze millions of rows. Daily reports will work. Thanks for mentioning the map/reduce of mongodb, I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary convern is to offer recommendations based on past user choices, you may also consider a graph database like Neo4j or FlockDB.

Those database would allow you to build relationship between buyers and the items they bought (which should be a lot less data to store, since you will have a lot less user data redundancies) which you can use to do some Triadic closure processes- In other words finding out what similar users bought that user 'A' did not buy yet.

I can not say I have done it yet, but I am also seriously looking into this.
Otherwise MongoDB in addition to the Map Reduce paradigm, has now (v 2.4.6) an Aggregation Pipeline Framework that I have found very powerful.